# iOS Core Data group by and return all the objects with all the property

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm new to Core Data and trying to do the following thing:

I want to fetch all the objects in the persistent store and group by an attribute called `day`. Meanwhile, all the objects should be sorted by an attribute called `startTime`.

Here is what I do:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Meeting"];    
// Add Sort Descriptors
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startTime" ascending:YES]]];
NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Meeting" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSAttributeDescription* meetingDay = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"day"];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:meetingDay, nil]];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:meetingDay]];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

But for results, what I got is a dictionary, which the key is 'day' and value is the day string.
How can I get all other attributes, basically I mean the whole objects?
Or do I need to fetch all the objects and do the group by myself?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the "group by"?  If you are planning to use a table view with a section for each `day`, then you should use an `NSFetchedResultsController`, with the underlying fetch sorted first by `day` and then by `startTime`, and specify the FRC's `sectionNameKeyPath` as `day`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete these lines from your fetch code...

```
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:meetingDay, nil]];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

The first limits your data set to one single entity attribute, yet you are wanting the entire entity.

The second specifies an `NSDictionary` result set, which as far as I understand from your question is unnecessary in this instance. You are seeking an `NSArray` of entities, not an `NSArray` containing an `NSDictionary` of entity attributes.

Comment: I think [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType] is necessary as group by need it. And if I remove the first line, I got: SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions

Comment: Maybe you could be a little more clear about what you are attempting to achieve? Otherwise I agree with pbasdf's comment above - use a FRC and set the `sectionNameKeyPath` as your entity attribute `day`

Comment: So what I want is to fetch all the objects and group by 'day'. Thanks

Comment: We are not mind readers, just normal people trying to help others and learn about coding. Your description is ridiculously short - I'd suggest you spend more time trying to imagine what it would be like trying to answer your question. So - to answer your question I have to make a number of assumptions... You are preparing a table view using a `UITableViewController`? You are attempting to gather all records for all attributes for one particular Entity in your Core Data object graph? You need a strong reference to that data so you can populate the table view using the `UITableViewController`?

Comment: If your answer to those questions is yes, then create a fetched results controller (FRC) within your table view controller class. Refer to `NSFetchedResultsController` documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/). When you instantiate your FRC, make certain you include your attribute `day` as the value for     `sectionNameKeyPath:`.